# SQL Proper JOIN. How can I simplify it?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
    COL.Seniority,
    COL.COLID AS COLCOL,
    MAIN.COLID AS MAINCOL,
    LINES.LINEID AS LINELINE,
    MAIN.LINEID AS MAINLINE,
    case when LineS.line = 1 then MAIN.Rate  end as BasicWage,
    case when LINES.Line = 2 then MAIN.Rate end as FixedOT
FROM PWPSC001_RATES MAIN
LEFT JOIN PWPSC001 POS
    ON POS.ID = MAIN.ID
LEFT JOIN PWPSC_RATES_COLUMNS COL
    ON COL.SEQNO = MAIN.SEQNO
LEFT JOIN PWPSC_RATES_LINES LINES
    ON LINES.LINEID = MAIN.LINEID
WHERE 
    MAIN.SEQNO = 355 AND MAIN.COLID = 6199 AND MAIN.ID = 7477
    AND MAIN.LINEID in(10355,20355) AND LINES.SEQNO =355
```

[image]

Additional Info:

[image]

How can I remove the NULL value in the last 2 columns and join it together?

Comment: Hi, can you please add the desired result. If I understood your problem correctly then use Inner join for Lines table instead of left outer join.

Comment: Do you simply want one column, instead of those two columns?

Comment: Hi I want to remove those NULL values and make it into 4 rows.

Comment: Your problem is that for each f the 4 'rows' you have 2 rows with lineid's of 10355 and 20355, thus each 'row' is 2 rows. You have to decide how you want to handle that; I can't tell you as I have no idea what any of the data actually means.

Comment: you will get NULL for either of the columns. because based on `case when LineS.line = 1 then MAIN.Rate  end as BasicWage,
    case when LINES.Line = 2 then MAIN.Rate end as FixedOT`, one of them will be NULL. are you fine for having them as NULL with 4 rows as you had told

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want aggregation:

```
SELECT COL.Seniority, COL.COLID AS COLCOL, MAIN.COLID AS MAINCOL, 
       MAX(case when LineS.line = 1 then MAIN.Rate end) as BasicWage,
       MAX(case when LINES.Line = 2 then MAIN.Rate end) as FixedOT
FROM PWPSC001_RATES MAIN LEFT JOIN
     PWPSC001 POS
     ON POS.ID = MAIN.ID LEFT JOIN
     PWPSC_RATES_COLUMNS COL
     ON COL.SEQNO = MAIN.SEQNO LEFT JOIN
     PWPSC_RATES_LINES LINES
     ON LINES.LINEID = MAIN.LINEID
WHERE MAIN.SEQNO = 355 AND MAIN.COLID = 6199 AND MAIN.ID = 7477 AND
      MAIN.LINEID IN (10355, 20355) AND LINES.SEQNO = 355
GROUP BY COL.Seniority, COL.COLID, MAIN.COLID;
```

Notice that I removed `MAINLINE` and `LINEID` from the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.  It isn't really needed because the corresponding values of interest end up in different columns -- you don't need those values separately.